# Searching multiple sites using Google Search API, siteSearch doesnt work

Tags: php, search

This is my request:

https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=MYKEY&q=flowers&alt=json&siteSearch=google.com|youtube.com&siteSearchFilter=i&cx=MYCXKEY

When I created the Google Search Engine i set a page but i want siteSearch to override that option and let me search more sites.

But it doesnt do anything?

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Could you be more clear in you question? What do you mean by "set a page"?

If you are trying to do a normal search, just take out the siteSearch and siteSearchFilter parameters.

If you are trying to exclude google.com & youtube.com then change your | to && and change siteSearchFilter from i to e.